# How does a biconditional with a quantifier get expanded?

Tags: first-order-logic, quantifiers

I know that $\alpha \Leftrightarrow \beta$ is equivalent to $(\alpha \Rightarrow \beta) \wedge (\beta \Rightarrow \alpha)$.

I want to expand the biconditional in $\forall x\exists y \text{ Qt}(x) \Leftrightarrow \left( \text{Pr}(x) \wedge \text{Sr}(y) \right)$ to two implications (with the end goal being to convert it to conjunctive normal form).

What happens to the quantifiers when the biconditional is expanded?

Does $\forall x \exists y$ stay with $\text{Qt}(x)$, as in $\left( \left( \forall x\exists y \text{ Qt}(x) \right) \Rightarrow \left( \text{Pr}(x) \wedge \text{Sr}(y) \right) \right) \wedge \left( \left( \text{Pr}(x) \wedge \text{Sr}(y) \right) \Rightarrow \left( \forall x\exists y \text{ Qt}(x) \right) \right)$?

Or does it stay on the left side of each implication, as in $\left( \left( \forall x\exists y \text{ Qt}(x) \right) \Rightarrow \left( \text{Pr}(x) \wedge \text{Sr}(y) \right) \right) \wedge \left( \left( \forall x\exists y \left( \text{Pr}(x) \wedge \text{Sr}(y) \right) \right) \Rightarrow \text{ Qt}(x) \right)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither?

You have 
$$  \forall x\exists y \text{ Qt}(x) \Leftrightarrow \left( \text{Pr}(x) \wedge \text{Sr}(y) \right)  \text{,}  $$
but what you *really* have is
$$  \forall x\exists y \bigg( \text{ Qt}(x) \Leftrightarrow \left( \text{Pr}(x) \wedge \text{Sr}(y) \right)  \bigg)  \text{.}  $$
The quantifiers *bind* the variables $x$ and $y$.  This means the quantifiers extend to the end of the binding.  Note that $x$ and $y$ are use on the right of the biimplication, so the quantified expression includes "$\left( \text{Pr}(x) \wedge \text{Sr}(y) \right)$".

Then 
$$  \forall x\exists y \text{ Qt}(x) \Leftrightarrow \left( \text{Pr}(x) \wedge \text{Sr}(y) \right)  $$
becomes 
$$  \forall x\exists y \bigg( \big( \text{ Qt}(x) \Rightarrow \left( \text{Pr}(x) \wedge \text{Sr}(y) \right) \big) \wedge \big( \left( \text{Pr}(x) \wedge \text{Sr}(y) \right) \Rightarrow \text{ Qt}(x) \big) \bigg) \text{.}  $$

Comment: That makes it seem much easier. How do you know that the quantifiers apply to the whole biconditional and not just the left side?

Comment: @wecsam : What would the symbols $x$ and $y$ on the right-hand side be?  Normally, one has a standard interpretation of the binding and normally that is until the end of the current scope (indicated by parentheses) or "to the right until the variable is bound again by a different quantifier".  Both of these give the same result here.  Other standards are possible, but rare.

Comment: I guess that $x$ and $y$ would not make sense on the right side. Thanks for your help.